# R Shiny - Creating a dynamic model from checkbox input

Tags: r, shiny

What I'm trying to do is based off of one checkbox input with 7 different options, create a reactive `glm` model based on which checkboxes the user has selected.

In my UI I have the following:

```
checkboxGroupInput("varChooser", label = h3("Variables to include in model:"), 
                                             choices = list("Gender", "Resident", "Citizen", "Pell", "Walk.In", "GPA","Ethnicity"),
                                             selected = list("Gender", "Resident", "Citizen", "Pell", "Walk.In", "GPA","Ethnicity"))
```

and in my SERVER I have the following:

```
studyModel <- reactive({
 glm(as.formula(paste("Status ~ ",paste0(input$varChooser,collapse="+"))), data=studyData, family = binomial)
 })

newStudent <- reactive({
data.frame(
  "Gender" = as.numeric(input$Gender),
  "Resident" = as.numeric(input$Resident),
  "Citizen" = as.numeric(input$Citizen),
  "Pell" = as.numeric(input$Pell),
  "Walk.In" = as.numeric(input$Walk.In),
  "GPA" = as.numeric(input$GPA),
  "Ethnicity" = as.numeric(input$Ethnicity)
)
})

goVal <- reactive({
predict(studyModel, newStudent(), type="response")
})
```

The `newStudent` dataframe works well, along with the reactive `goVal`, but I am trying to add the dynamic model instead of having one model.

The error I am getting is:

```
Error: no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "c('reactiveExpr', 'reactive')"
```

Comment: As `studyModel` is a reactive you need to call it with parenthesis `predict(studyModel(), newStudent(), type="response")`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - I didn't have the parenthesis after `studyModel` in my `predict` function